# Настройка уведомления при вызове его через AlarmManger

Tags: java, android, eclipse, broadcast-receiver

Есть вот такое окошко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем пишется текст и устанавливается дата, потом в указанное время должно всплывать уведомление с заданным текстом. Уведомление есть, но с текстом проблемы, никак не могу разобраться, как его туда правильно запихнуть. 
Из всех вариантов, что я перепробовал, самый действенный отправлять текст в BroadcastReceiver, а потом при вызове метода (который создает уведомление) передавать его в само уведомление, но этот способ работает некорректно. Первый раз текст передается, а при последующем редактировании текст остается, тот что был передан первым.

У меня есть два класса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Reminder - основной. При вызове метода saveText я создаю AlarmManager и передаю текст из текстового поля editT в Alarm класс

```
void saveText() {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Reminder.this, Alarm.class);
    intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("edit.text", editT.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("title.text", getResources().getString(R.string.reminder));
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Reminder.this, 0, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);  
}
```

В Alarm (который наследуется от BroadcastReceiver) я получаю данные и вызываю метод generateNotification (который находится в том же Reminder) с параметрами: название и текст для уведомления.

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

Reminder reminder = new Reminder();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   String e = intent.getStringExtra("edit.text");
   String t = intent.getStringExtra("title.text");

        reminder.generateNotification(context, e, t);
}
```

И в Reminder наконец вызывается этот метод

```
 public void generateNotification(Context context, String text, String title){


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Edit.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification2) // Small icon
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher)) // Large icon
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(title)  // Content title
            .setContentText(text); // Content text

    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);

}
```

Где я уже и создаю уведомление с текстом полученным из Alarm.

Вроде всё правильно, но текст от тестового поля до уведомления доходит только при первом создании напоминания, а если текст в тестовом поле поменять и переписать напоминание, в уведомлении остается всё тот же первый вариант.

Подскажите где здесь ошибка или метод получше, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Если у вас title не меняется то вы его же из ресурсов берёте

Comment: title не меняется с ним все нормально. Меня интересует текст, с текстового поля editT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранять текст в SharedPreference (ваш метод saveText())

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("edit.text", e);
editor.putString("title.text", t);
editor.apply();
```

Когда необходимо достать (метод onReceive()):

```
String e = pref.getString("edit.text", "default edit text");
String t = pref.getString("title.text", "default title");
```

Comment: Пробовал, но программа выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую? а лучше выложите StackTrace ошибки

Comment: в onReceive надо тоже вызвать SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Метод getSharedPreferences в onReceive не находит  -   [Скрин ошибки](http://s019.radikal.ru/i612/1601/55/d3ac5b551c29.png)

Comment: Сам разобрался, нужно: SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

```
  `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Edit.class);` Что такое `Edit.class`?
```

Скорей всего это происходит из-за того, что
 `PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` всегда регистрирует на нулевой айдишник(второй параметр), который Вы уже зарегистрировали.

Comment: Я тоже это предполагал, а как изменить ситуацию не подскажете?